# How to remove a brick & mortar planter from inside a home

Tags: brick

Just purchased a 1959 ranch home and it looks like what is now the family room may have been an enclosed porch in the past.

There is an odd knee-high brick planter box ( ? ) along a painted paneled wall. Just the two ends attach to the wall, the rest of the box is hollow. It looks like this if you can imagine the short ends attached to the wall.

Is there a way I can remove this without doing too much damage to the wall?

Thank you in advance for any advice you might have!

[image]

Comment: Got to have a pic.

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies. I will try to attach a photo. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Laura,  i added the photo to your question so please delete the "**answer**" below. You can take a tour of how this site works to better understand how things are done here. https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: It may just be touching the Sheetrock with out a picture with the shelf off we can only guess. Remember if you take this out there will be a hole in the carpet. And the wall will probably need some paint and possibly texture touch up.

Comment: The mortar does touch the wall. The carpet will eventually be replaced and luckily the prior owner left the excess carpet that we can use until that is done. Yes, the wall does have some texture but will be painted soon. Hopefully we won't damage the wall when we remove the brick. There is linoleum under the brick so I'm guessing this was some sort of all weather room in the past, maybe a sun porch.